# Need to configure regular expression that can be applied to each line in the build log to set build description as jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Could use `Jenkins description setter plugin` in Jenkins UI to set the build description to the matched regex from build logs, but I failed to replicate the same functionality as Jenkins script, used the below lines but ended up with errors.
[image]

```
publishers {
                buildDescription(/^build-descrip: (.*)/)
            } 


O/p

[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'publishers' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleBuild, MavenDescriptorStep, VersionNumber, addInteractivePromotion, ansiColor, archive, artifactoryDistributeBuild, artifactoryDownload, artifactoryEditProps, artifactoryMavenBuild, artifactoryNpmInstall, artifactoryNpmPublish, artifactoryPromoteBuild, artifactoryUpload, bat, build, catchError, checkout, collectEnv, conanAddRemote, conanAddUser, container, containerLog, deleteDir, deployArtifacts, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, dockerNode, dockerPullStep, dockerPushStep, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, findBuildScans, findFiles, getArtifactoryServer, getContext, git, initConanClient, input, isUnix, jiraComment, jiraIssueSelector, jiraSearch, junit, library, libraryResource, load, lock, logstash, logstashSend, mail, milestone, newArtifactoryServer, newBuildInfo, newGradleBuild, newMavenBuild, newNpmBuild, node, nodesByLabel, parallel, podTemplate, powershell, properties, publishBuildInfo, publishHTML, pwd, readCSV, readFile, readJSON, readManifest, readMavenPom, readProperties, readTrusted, readYaml, resolveScm, retry, rtAddInteractivePromotion, rtBuildInfo, rtDeleteProps, rtDockerPush, rtDownload, rtGradleDeployer, rtGradleResolver, rtGradleRun, rtMavenDeployer, rtMavenResolver, rtMavenRun, rtNpmDeployer, rtNpmInstall, rtNpmPublish, rtNpmResolver, rtPromote, rtPublishBuildInfo, rtServer, rtSetProps, rtUpload, runConanCommand, script, sh, sha1, slackSend, sleep, sloccountPublish, sshagent, stage, stash, step, svn, tee, timeout, tm, tool, touch, unarchive, unstable, unstash, unzip, vSphere, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitUntil, warnError, withContext, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, wrap, writeCSV, writeFile, writeJSON, writeMavenPom, writeYaml, ws, xrayScan, xrayScanBuild, zip] or symbols [all, allOf, always, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, attach, authorizationMatrix, batchFile, bitbucket, booleanParam, branch, brokenBuildSuspects, brokenTestsSuspects, buildAllBranches, buildAnyBranches, buildButton, buildChangeRequests, buildDescription, buildDiscarder, buildName, buildNamedBranches, buildNoneBranches, buildParameter, buildRegularBranches, buildTags, buildingTag, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, certificate, changeRequest, changelog, changeset, checkoutToSubdirectory, choice, choiceParam, cleanWs, clock, cloud, command, configFile, configFileProvider, configMapVolume, containerEnvVar, containerLivenessProbe, containerTemplate, copyArtifactPermission, copyArtifacts, credentials, cron, crumb, culprits, default, defaultView, demand, developers, disableConcurrentBuilds, disableResume, docker, dockerCert, dockerfile, downloadSettings, downstream, dumb, durabilityHint, elasticSearch, emptyDirVolume, emptyDirWorkspaceVolume, envVar, envVars, environment, equals, exact, expression, extendedChoice, file, fileParam, filePath, findText, fingerprint, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, fromScm, fromSource, git, gitHubBranchDiscovery, gitHubBranchHeadAuthority, gitHubForkDiscovery, gitHubTagDiscovery, gitHubTrustContributors, gitHubTrustEveryone, gitHubTrustNobody, gitHubTrustPermissions, gitParameter, github, githubPush, globalConfigFiles, gradle, headRegexFilter, headWildcardFilter, hostPathVolume, hostPathWorkspaceVolume, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, inheriting, inheritingGlobal, installSource, isRestartedRun, jacoco, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobName, kubernetes, label, lastCompleted, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, lastSuccessful, lastWithArtifacts, latestSavedBuild, legacy, legacySCM, list, local, location, logParser, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, logstash, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, modernSCM, msbuild, msbuildError, msbuildWarning, myView, never, newContainerPerStage, nfsVolume, nfsWorkspaceVolume, node, nodeProperties, nonInheriting, nonStoredPasswordParam, none, not, onFailure, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parallelsAlwaysFailFast, parameters, password, pattern, permalink, permanent, persistentVolumeClaim, persistentVolumeClaimWorkspaceVolume, pipeline-model, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, podAnnotation, podEnvVar, pollSCM, portMapping, preserveStashes, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, rabbitMq, rateLimitBuilds, recipients, redis, regex, remotingCLI, requestor, rule, run, runParam, s3CopyArtifact, s3Upload, schedule, scmRetryCount, scriptApprovalLink, search, secretEnvVar, secretVolume, security, shell, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, slackNotifier, slave, sourceRegexFilter, sourceWildcardFilter, specific, ssh, sshPublisher, sshPublisherDesc, sshTransfer, sshUserPrivateKey, stackTrace, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, syslog, tag, text, textParam, tmpSpace, toolLocation, triggeredBy, unsecured, upstream, [![upstreamDevelopers, userSeed, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, weather, wil][1]][1]dcards, withAnt, workspace, zfs, zip] or globals
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute JobDSL in pipelineDSL. That won't work

The pipelineDSL syntax to edit the build description is

```
currentBuild.description = "my new description"
```

wrap it in a script block if you are using declarative pipeline

To parse build logs, you should use sh step return output

```
def myVar = sh (
    script: 'echo "toto"',
    returnStdout: true
).trim()
```

now on the myVar variable you can use regex

```
def myRegexResult = (myVar =~ /myRegex/)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but the above solution is a static assignment of "my new description" but i want the description to be set from the build logs which is dynamic, fetched with the regex specified.

Comment: I believe you can set currentBuild from post step cant you? 
```
    post { 
        always { 
            script {
                currentBuild.description = description
            }
        }
    }
```
where description would be a variable that contains the errors you got from the return output of your sh commands

Comment: actual its nor error, its that's regex expression, basically, what should happen is, the regex expression is searched on the build logs, so anything that match, is printed as build description, we has some md5sum values that's printed so we to set that in pipeline, easy on the Jenkins UI using description setter plugin as shown above

Comment: I updated my answer. You should not parse jenkins build logs but parse the return output of your sh command

Comment: Thanks a lot, ya I'll have to do that, if the description setter plugin has no pipeline support.

Answer (score 0):

In the scripted pipeline, you can do it like -

```
timestamps {
  node() {
    currentBuild.description = "text"
    currentBuild.displayName = "text"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but the above solution is a static assignment of "text" but i want the description to be set from the build logs which is dynamic, fetched with the regex specified.

Comment: You can even populate it with variable too as example - currentBuild.displayName = "#${currentBuild.number}-${BRANCH_NAME}". does this helps?

Comment: nope, basically, what should happen is, the regex expression is searched on the build logs, so anything that match, is printed as build description, we has some md5sum values that's printed so we to set that in pipeline, easy on the Jenkins UI using description setter plugin as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Using the plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy-postbuild/

```
def matcher = manager.getLogMatcher(".*Total time: (.*)\$")
if(matcher?.matches()) {
    manager.addShortText(matcher.group(1), "grey", "white", "0px", "white")
}
```